# Focus on invisible VBA after Excel start

Tags: excel, vba, focus, startup

When launching Excel 2010 via the Start menu, the Excel window opens and shows an empty workbook, but the window does **not** have the focus. Thanks to a tool called WindowsFocusLogger I was able to verify that the Excel **task** does have the focus.

More or less by chance I then found that by typing **ALT-F11**, the focus moves to the visible Excel window. So the focus was on the invisible VBA window right after launching Excel. Since some time, this happens with every Excel startup.

My Normal.dotm template does not contain any code. Any ideas?

Comment: Alt-F11 is the short cut key for swtiching to VBA regardless of Word/Excel/Powerpoint and this would be the focus.

Comment: Why is this a problem?  What is the undesirable behaviour please?

Comment: When you launch an application you expect it to be in focus, i.e. ready to input data without a prior click on its window.
Update:
- Repairing Excel installation did not solve the problem
- Disabling the Solver add-in solved the problem
- when re-enabling the Solver add-in, the problem is back again.